# GoFlex Seagate 2 TB HFS+ Journaled would not mount

Tags: macos, hard-drive

Guys I got GoFlex Segate 2TB OSX Journaled
The error I get:

```
sudo fsck_hfs -r -d /dev/disk1s1
journal_replay(/dev/disk1s1) returned 16
** /dev/rdisk1s1
  Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=98304 cacheSize=3145728K.
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-305.10.1).
  could not get volume block 2, err 16
  could not get alternate volume header at 409598, err 16
volumeType is 0
0000:  00a0 bd01 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
0010:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
01f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
  unknown volume type
  primary MDB is at block 0 0x00
  alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00
  primary VHB is at block 0 0x00
  alternate VHB is at block 0 0x00
  sector size = 512 0x200
  VolumeObject flags = 0x01
  total sectors for volume = 409600 0x64000
  total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00
  CheckForClean - unknown volume type
```

Update:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *960.2 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS iMac-SSD                959.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS                         2.0 TB     disk1s2
sudo gpt -r show disk1
gpt show: unable to open device 'disk1': Resource busy
diskutil verifyVolume disk1s2
Started file system verification on disk1s2
Verifying file system
File system check exit code is 8
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 8: POSIX reports: Exec format error
```

I am on OS X El Captain. The disk is OS Journaled file type 100%. My mate was painting and he moved the drive and caused unsafe disconnect. Now First aid reports problems with Partition map.

What does this mean? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! To make it easier for us to help you, please be more specific about what's happening and what steps you have taken to resolve it. Some good information would be: computer model and year, OS, whether or not this drive has ever worked before, what you have tried to do, etc.

Comment: disk1s1 usually neither is HFS nor journaled but EFI (FAT32), so fsck_hfs as well as replaying journals won't help here.

Comment: I am on OS X El Captain. The disk is OS Journaled file type 100%. My mate was painting and he moved the drive and caused unsafe disconnect. Now First aid reports problems with Partition map. I know how to use terminal so if anyone can give me the right commands this should be quick to fix.

Comment: @klanomath output posted above

Comment: @klanomath same return: sudo gpt -r show disk1
Password:
gpt show: unable to open device 'disk1': Resource busy

Comment: diskutil verifyVolume disk1
Error starting file system verification for (bad disk ref): Disk object invalid or unable to serialize (-69810)

Comment: @MarsSpiders gpt and diskutil are two different tools. `gpt` reads(/writes) the partition table of a disk and requires a disk as argument. `diskutil verifyVolume ...` requires a partition (volume) as argument. Therefore `sudo gpt -r show disk1` and `diskutil verifyVolume disk1s2`. Simply copy & paste the commands! If the disk is stubborn detach and reattach it. You have to get a possible new / different disk identifier of the drive with `diskutil list` before entering`sudo gpt ...` or `diskutil ...`.

Comment: @klanomath see above UPDATE 2

Comment: @MarsSpiders Solve you this?